# Error while running phpunit test in yii framework

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, phpunit, yii

I just tried to run the unit test of the blog for the yii framework. But I got such error and i am not able to resolve the problem. Please feel free to share with me. Thank you in advance. And I got such error.

Do i need to set up the test database for the phpunit. If so how should i have to do it.

```
C:\wamp\www\yii\demos\blog\protected\tests>phpunit --verbose unit\CommentTest
C:\wamp\www\yii\demos\blog\protected\tests/../config/test.phpPHPUnit 3.6.10 by S
ebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\yii\demos\blog\protected\tests\phpunit.xml

EE

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 7.75Mb

There were 2 errors:

1) CommentTest::testFindRecentComments
CDbException: The table "{{post}}" for active record class "Post" cannot be foun
d in the database.

C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php:2264
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php:379
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CDbFixtureManager.php:301
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CDbTestCase.php:118
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\phpunit:46

2) CommentTest::testApprove
CException: Table 'tbl_post' does not exist.

C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CDbFixtureManager.php:254
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CDbFixtureManager.php:145
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CDbFixtureManager.php:305
C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CDbTestCase.php:118
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 2.
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally, I found the solution to this problem. It means that it doesn't find the table in the database. So, I executed this schema.mysql.sql file which was under the directory blog/protected/data. And everything worked fine –